# Finding a basis and dimension of a vector space of 3x3 matrices whose column, row and diagonal sums are zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How does one find a basis (and thus dimension) of a vector space of 3x3 matrices such that:
-sum of elements of each column is zero (3 conditions)
-sum of elements of each row is zero (also 3 conditions)
-sum of elements on one diagonal = sum of elements on second diagonal = zero (2 conditions)

Trying to find a basis by solving a large system by hand doesn't look like a good option.

Comment: Before solving "a large system" you could consider some examples. How many examples of such matrices did you find so far (except for the zero matrix, of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we start by filling out
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&\phantom0&\phantom0\\
b&c&\phantom0\\
\phantom0&\phantom0&\phantom0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then we see that all the other elements are forced. For instance, the one below the $b$ must be $-a-b$, and then the two remaining corners are forced, and after that, all the edges only have one remaining unfilled element, so they are forced.

What will these entries be filled by? Well, going in the order described above, I get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&-2a-b+c&a+b-c\\
b&c&-b+2c\\
-a-b&2a+b+c&-a-c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
To fill this out I have used the conditions on all the columns and rows that do not go through the middle, and I've used both the diagonals. What conditions remain unused are the middle row and the middle column. These two conditions give
$$\begin{align}
&\cases{b+c-b+2c = 0\\
-2a-b+c+c+2a+b+c = 0
}\\
\vphantom 0\\
&\cases{3c = 0\\
3c = 0
}\end{align}
$$
which is to say we must have $c = 0$. However, that's all the restrictions we have. Pick $a$ and $b$ more or less freely to find your two basis elements.

Apparently the conditions weren't all independent. One explicit dependence is that if we know that each row sums to $0$, then we know that the entire matrix sums to $0$. But then, since the left and middle columns each sum to $0$ we can deduce the condition that the right column also sums to $0$. So one of the row / column conditions was indeed superfluous.

Comment: This is basically the same as your "solving a large system by hand", but I eliminate six of the equations immediately by substitution as I fill in the matrix.